# Delete Duplicates from Array in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that removes any duplicated values in an array without changing the order of the values. The output should look as follows:

```
5 3 7 1 7 7 2 3 5 5
5 3 7 1 2
```

However in my program the new array whose duplicated values have been deleted does not print.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int unique(int array[], int n) {

    if (n==0 || n==1)
        return n;
    
    int temp[n];
    
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < n -1; i++)
        if (array[i] != array[i+1])
            temp[j++] = array[i];
    
    temp[j++] = array[n-1];
    
    for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
        array[i] = temp[i];
    
    return j;
}

int main() {
    int array[10];
    int n, i;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cin >> array[i];

    int size = unique(array, n);

    if(size < 0 || size > 10)
        return -1;

    for(int size = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I reworked the code after I received some advice about the constraints and the size of the array. I also eliminated the use of `temp` since it is not correct C++. Here is the new code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int unique(int array[]) {
    int size = 10;
    int i, j, k;

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        for(j = i + 1; j <size;){
            if(array[i]==array[j]){
                for( k = j; k<size-1;++k)
                    array[k]=array[k+1];
                
                --size;
            }
            else
                ++j;
        }

    return size;
}

int main() {
    int array[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cin >> array[i];

    int size = unique(array);

    if(size < 0 || size > 10)
        return -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (array[i] != array[i+1])` -- How is this going to detect the duplicates if the numbers are not next to each other?  I think you need to rethink the logic, and probably use a different data structure to "remember" the values already seen.  For example: `[8 1 2 3 4 5 8]` --  How will you detect that `8`is a duplicate?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Even with the numbers right next to each other it does not print anything but you are right. Since I am a beginner, I do not know how to use ```std::vector<int> temp(n)``` yet.

Comment: Using `std::vector` is how you do dynamic arrays in C++.  Second thing is that your logic is wrong -- the value you return from `unique` determines how many to print (the `size` variable).  Why not print out the return value from `unique` to see how many will print?  Don't be surprised if it is 0 or less.  So you need to get the logic of `unique` working first.  Also, a beginner to C++ wouldn't get these types of problems -- this sounds like a problem from one of the online coding websites.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are correct, it prints out zero when I directly print what ```unique``` returns.

Comment: `for(int size = 0; i < size; i++)` -- Also, take a look closely at this line.  Do you see something wrong?  Also, is it only 10 numbers, or can the array be of any size?  What is the maximum number of numbers?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That line is definitely wrong. It should be ```for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)``` if I am not mistaken. Yes, the idea is for the max size to be 10.

Comment: What about `unique` itself?  What is the maximum size `n`?   If it's also going to be 10, then why pass `n`, when you can simply not pass it and directly declare `int temp[10];` within `unique`?  The reason for these questions is that the optimal answer is dependent on what the constraints are.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think it would be better to get rid of ``n`` and replace it with ``int size = 10`` and then work with that instead. I reworked the code a little bit. I would like to show you but through comments it is difficult.

Comment: Please update the original post with the code, and not put it in the comments.  However, do not change the original code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In the end I would return using ``return size``. I just ran the code and it seems to work. It is probably not the neatest and most optimal but it works.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I updated the post with the new code. By the way, I eliminated the use of ``temp`` as well.

Answer (score 1):

First deleting elements from your array means that it needs to be resized so it is better to use a vector.

The basic idea is this

1. store the values you have seen in some data structure, called it map. In C++ std::unordered_map uses a hash table therefore search and insert are O(1)
2. Scan the vector element by element
3. lookup the element in map if it is there delete the element
4. Otherwise add the element to map and continue to the next element

[C++ implementation](https://gist.github.com/hikmatfarhat-ndu/5f61938b16d220f958ca40d270e8ffa8)

EDIT:

As PaulMckenzie suggested it is better to use std::unordered_set which is true in this case as there is no need for values in this case only keys

Comment: Better to use `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right i just edited the post.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But `unordered_set` won't maintain the original order of elements either.

Comment: The set won't be used to maintain the order.  It would be used simply as a way to determine what has already been seen.  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9373fdfd3afd9dc)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `std::vector` instead of a an array, or use `std::array` if you know the number of elements at compile time. Here's a solution that works for arrays, or any STL containers (with some slight syntax modifications, namely using `std::begin` and `std::end`):

```
int unique(int *arr, int n)
{
  auto end = arr + n;

  for (auto begin = arr; begin != end; ++begin)
    end = std::remove(begin + 1, end, *begin);

  return end - arr;
}
```