# How to dedup an unsorted vector within O(nlogn) while keeping its original order?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, duplicates, time-complexity

I was reviewing Data Structure. In the text book, there is a paragraph saying

> "The direct approach is to sort it first, then uniquify it just as a
> sorted vector. Both steps can be finished within O(nlogn)."

then

> "However there is a side-effect: the relative order of the items
> cannot be preserved."

finally

> "Actually we can eliminate this side-effect without increasing the
> time complexity. Please implement it yourself."

Cannot find any clue. I'm not using STL right now while reviewing the text book. All I can imagine is to try to alter something during mergesort.

Anyone who's having a brighter view?

Sample case

Input: 5, 3, 5, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8, 13

Output: 5, 3, 8, 13

Comment: You can create an array on indices `[0 1 2 ..i.. n-1]` and sort it with respect to the values of `A[i]`. Then, you can use the sorted array of indices to detect the duplicates, without having modified the order of the original `A[]` array

Comment: [Already asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346313/delete-duplicates-from-array-in-c/64346650#comment113801370_64346650)

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach:

- Build a copy of your std::vector; in the copy, instead of simple elements, store pairs (element, index) *[complexity: O(n)]*;
- Sort the copy *[complexity: O(n log n)]*;
- Move duplicates out of the copy to a new data structure *[complexity: O(n)]*;
- For every pair (element, index) in the duplicate data structure, remove the element at that index in the original std::vector *[complexity: O(n); see for instance the question [Erasing multiple objects from a std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487717/erasing-multiple-objects-from-a-stdvector)]*.

Total complexity: O(n + n log n + n + n) = O(n log n). Sorting is the longest step.

Alternative approaches in python with benchmarks: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark (note: these alternative approaches might be different than the sort-then-dedup approach - for instance, some use python's `set` which supports test for membership in O(1)).

See also these questions:

- [In python, how do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/3080723)
- [In C++, what's the most efficient way to erase duplicates and sort a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector)

Comment: Nice try bro, except the time complexity issue I guess

Comment: @StevenLiang Your guess is pessimistic; I edited with more information about the time complexity.

Comment: The referenced unsorted and sorted data structures are both vectors in my book. The text book is talking about Data Structures in C++. When performing the removing step, the worst case optimal complexity can be O(n^2). If a linked list is used, it's rather easy indeed in O(n).

Comment: No, removing duplicates in a sorted `std::vector` is O(n) if you do it carefully.

Comment: @StevenLiang In fact, that's why we sort it first. Removing duplicates naively from an unsorted vector would be n^2.

Comment: I edited the question body in order to improve readability. The text book means keeping the relative order in the unsorted undedupped vector IMO.

Comment: @StevenLiang Oh, are you talking about the fourth step? "For every pair (element, index) in the duplicate data structure, remove the element at that index in the original std::vector"? That's also O(n) if you do it carefully.

Comment: Yes the last step. Removing an item in the original vector takes O(n), then it gets multiplied by O(n) since the count of duplicates is input-sensitive and not guaranteed.

Comment: @StevenLiang: Yes. Your argument shows that there exists an algorithm to perform the last step in worst-case Θ(n^2). However, there also exists a somewhat-less-naive algorithm which is worst-case Θ(n).

Comment: @StevenLiang See for instance the question [Erasing multiple objects from a std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487717/erasing-multiple-objects-from-a-stdvector)